# How do you change the currency in open edx ironwood?

Tags: django, e-commerce, django-oscar, openedx

I have open edx and its ecommerce application fully installed and working. 
The platform has a default currency set to USD but I need it set to Euros

Some forums online suggested changing the currency variable in lms.env.json as well as the currency variable in course mode within the LMS admin.

However this hasn't worked for me.

There are no other solutions on the internet.

Has anyone incurred and solved this problem?

Comment: `django-oscar` (which you have tagged this question with) has a setting `OSCAR_DEFAULT_CURRENCY` that can be set to potentially change the currency?  https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/ref/settings.html#currency-settings

Comment: I changed this variable to 'gbp' from 'usd' and then rebooted the system. It didn't work - do I need to compile the system? if so how do I do this?

Comment: I compiled the system and changed this variable. This doesn't seem to work.